# Software to build GraphQL schema without database

Tags: database, ide

I am new to [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) and the problem I am designing for does not seem to be a popular choice for examples or tutorials.

I want to make a schema for a database that is behind a REST API.  I can't directly connect to the DB to use introspection. The REST API is abstract for the data tables.  One call for any and all table data.

I have a logical schema of the DB to work with in making the GraphQL schema.  I would like to make the GraphQL schema then add the logic for the resolvers later.

I have tried Playground as a GraphQL IDE but it does not like that I do not have an endpoint.

Is there another IDE that can help me make the schema or am I going to have to wing it with Notepad++?

Comment: I think that I am too stupid to understand the question.  But, if you just want to draw a schema, what's wrong with MySql Workbench?

Comment: Not draw a schema but make a GraphQL schema.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I had never heard of https://graphql.org/  It does look interesting